# Newspaper ownership data

Tags: data-request, companies, media, publishing

Is there a dataset of the ownership of newspapers in America? For example, it is common knowledge that Jeff Bezos owns the Washington Post, and that News Corp has bought the Wall Street Journal. I would like to extend that to look at local newspapers around the countries (such as all those listed [here](http://newseum.org/todaysfrontpages/).